# Formatting date to human readable format

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp, date-formatting

Lets say in my mysql database I have a timestamp `2013-09-30 01:16:06` and lets say this variable is `$ts`.

*How can I output this to show more like `September 30th, 2013`?*

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
$timestamp = "2013-09-30 01:16:06";
echo date("F jS, Y", strtotime($timestamp)); //September 30th, 2013
```

Note the use of `S` to get the english ordinal suffix for the day.

Since you're already using `strtotime` if you need a human readable  data for the *current time* you can just use the keyword "*now*" as in `strtotime("now")`

**Related sources**

- [Date](http://php.net/manual/function.date.php)
- [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 26):

Use `strtotime()` to convert that string into a Unix Timestamp, then use the `date()` function to display it like you want.

```
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a",strtotime($ts));
```

Reference:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that php is even needed there. Check MySQL [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

*Example:*

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2013-09-30 01:16:06', '%M %D, %Y %H:%i:%s') as `readable`;
```

*Result:*

```
September 30th, 2013 01:16:06
```

*For real usage:*

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(`date_column`, '%M %D, %Y %H:%i:%s') as `readable`
FROM
    `your_table`;
```

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky , Thanks a lot. My english still requires improvement `:(`

Comment: Cheers, That's nothing big to be sad about :)

Answer (score 3):

```
echo date("F d Y",strtotime("2013-09-30 01:16:06"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
<?php
$date = '2013-09-30 01:16:06';
$convertDate = date('F jS, Y h:i:s', strtotime($date));
echo $convertDate;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Mysql query**

```
 select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime_field) as datetime_field from table;
```

**PHP**

```
echo date("F d Y", $datetime_field )
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `diffForHumans` function:

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($ts)->diffForHumans()
```